# Leveling Gene Ontology represented by a graph

Tags: algorithm, graph, bioinformatics

I uploaded a full Gene Ontology Terms file from this link http://www.geneontology.org/GO.downloads.ontology.shtml

I represented the data by a graph where GO Terms are nodes and isA and PartOf relationships are edges. According to my research, there should be only one root in this graph which is the GO Term with the accession "GO:0008150".

Now, I wish to assign a level for each GO Term in order to do some algorithms. I assumed that the level of the node is the number of nodes on the longest path starting from the root and ending at the node to be assigned the level.

The problem is that, out of around 60,000 terms, I found only around 30,000 nodes are reachable from the root. Therefore, the remaining 30,000 terms can not have a level. This prevents me from doing my algorithm.

What are the solution to this problem?

Here's a solution that I thought of, do you think this is a good idea?

The GO terms that can't be leveled do not have parents. However, almost all of them, (except the leaves) have sons,Therefore, my idea is to check the son with the deepest level for each of these nodes, and then to assign the node its son level at the deepest level minus 1. For example, if we have 3 sons at level 1 - 3 - 5 , we assign the father the level 4 because it's the level of the deepest son minus 1 level.`

Answer (score 1):

More directly, I would contact the GO Helpdesk with questions--they are pretty responsive:

go-helpdesk at ebi.ac.uk

There are three ontologies in the file that you downloaded, of which GO:0008150 is just one root. Moreover, is_a and part_of are not sufficient to fully connect the graph even if you did use all three ontologies--there are a lot of other relations involved, and transitivity can be complicated, especially when considering multiple paths:

http://www.geneontology.org/GO.ontology.relations.shtml

Finally, you might want to consider what information you're actually trying to extract from the graph as "level" in the GO (a fraught concept) does not actually carry very much, if any, information.

Answer (score 0):

GO contains 3 main parts: biological processes, cellular components and molecular functions. Are you sure you've removed the 2 other components from your dataset ?
You could also ask http://www.biostars.org